# Making a middlewear that blocks adds in apps?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am already going into the assumption that this is either a really bad idea, illegal, or not even possible. I am completely new to Android app development, but have done a lot of desktop development and web development over the years.

Someone came to me asking if I could make an app that blocks pop-ups and ads present in other apps. Is something like this possible without knowing the internals of other apps? I imagine that if something like this were possible it would also cause security issues, no?

Something like this is absolutely possible with something like a web browser via extensions (uBlock Origin, etc.) because the code that goes into making websites is readily available for people to see and manipulate as they please, but phone apps are (usually) completely closed source.

Thoughts?

Comment: In general it is not allowed to publish such apps on the play store. All such Apps act as an VPN. One variant is where the app acts as an vpn and redirect all internet traffic through it(on device). Others are regular vpn services that filter the trafic on their servers.

Comment: @ViatcheslavEhrmann Thanks for the response. I saw that something like this would conflict with play store guidelines as well. I have seen some solutions involving a vpn as well, but the ones I have seen are for certain browsers, not necessarily other apps (Facebook, etc.).